# .NET framework compiler and assembly registration tool has stopped working

Tags: .net

When I try to build a C# based project or the setup & deployment project, I get the following error on the visual studio environment:

[image]

[image]

The error tab displays the following:

Error   2   "LC.exe" exited with code -1073741819.

I have researched this online and could not find any concrete solution online. Why would this happen anyway?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,

Subbu

Comment: They are crashing with error code 0xc0000005, an access violation.  That's a nasty one, you need to get your machine stable again.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks for the reply. I might just reinstall visual studio.

Comment: I had an identical problem and simply removing all of the content from licenses.licx solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to uninstall and reinstall your Microsoft .Net Framework.
That should work.